# Build Ghostscript 10 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, xorg, compiling, source, ghostscript

In official repositories of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS there is a Ghostscript 9.55. I'm trying to build latest Ghostscript 10 from sources. It's working but…

a) when I type 'sudo checkinstall' it creates a deb package and installs it, in Synaptic I see latest version, but there is a conflict with ghostscript-x package which is still in version 9.55.

[image: Ghostscript in Synaptic]

b) when I type 'sudo make install' it installs bins, but in Synaptic I still see original version.

My question is, how can I build ghostscript-x package relevant to Ghostscript 10?

Comment: Do you actually need a `ghostscript-x` package? AFAIK it just provides X11 driver support, and only in the case that the binary is configured for dynamically loaded drivers (which does not seem to be the default). What is the actual issue that you are trying to solve? If you run `gs -h` and examine the `Available devices` section, do you see all the devices mentioned [here](https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/Devices.htm#x11_devices)?

Comment: @steeldriver I don't know if I need it. This was installed by default. Apparently it is related to the ubuntu-desktop package -- marking for removal also marks the ubuntu-desktop package. I don't know how else to disable it.
Default Ghostscript shows devices: x11, x11alpha, x11cmyk, x11cmyk2, x11cmyk4, x11cmyk8, x11gray2, x11gray4, x11mono.